# How to add nested fields in IONIC2/ Angular2 form with seperate add button

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic2, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I am in need to add nested fields in a form. I followed exactly this tutorial http://brophy.org/post/nested-reactive-forms-in-angular2/.

Although every thing is working fine for me, except that I need the add button to be with every child and on clicking on which the child is added in between them.

ex: if there are

child1  add-btn
child2  add-btn
child3  add-btn
child4  add-btn

now if add-btn of child2 is clicked then the new field should be inserted after child2.

**I tried:** using a tag in for loop as below it shows add button but on clicking that new field is inserted at end always that is not desired.

```
 <a href="" (click)="addChild()">
        Add Child
    </a>
```

**What I think:** That I can pass id as below in add function and then insert into an array at that index. But unfortunately not getting how to do that.

```
(click)="addChild(idx)";
```

Hope it's clear. Please let me know if I can achieve the desired using this approach. Thanks in advance.

**Answer:**  After all I followed https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2 ..
and solved by -

```
control.insert(i+1, addCtrl);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just store the index of the ngFor loop like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index;">
    {{item.name}}
    <a href="" (click)="addChild(i)">
        Add Child
    </a>
</div>
```

The variable i will now store the index of each item, and on button click events the index of the item will be sent as a parameter to the addChild() method. You can then add an new item to that position in your component:

```
export class FieldsComponent {

    items: Array<any> = [
        {name: 'item1'}, 
        {name: 'item2'}, 
        {name: 'item3'}, 
        {name: 'item4'}
    ];

    addChild(index: number): void {
        //Insert after the index of the clicked button
        items.splice(index + 1, 0, {name: 'Added item'});
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But in my case insert function in working perfectly as:   control.insert(i+1, addCtrl);

Answer (score 0):

After all I followed https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2 .. and solved by -

```
control.insert(i+1, addCtrl);
```

Hope it will help someone.